# Runge Kutta 4th order with coupled equations where derivatives are linked

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I have 2 coupled second order equations as below:
$$ \ddot{y}(t) + a\dot{y}(t) + by(t)=q(t) $$
$$ \ddot{q}(t) + c\dot{q}(t) + dq(t) = A\ddot{y}(t)$$

I'm wondering if it is possible to solve this system using Runge Kutta 4th order? My problem here is the second derivative of y in the second equation. How to handle it?

**EDIT:**
Here below is the system of equations I considered:

$$ \dot{y}(t) = w(t) $$
$$ \ddot{y}(t) = \dot{w}(t) = -aw(t) - by(t)+q(t) $$
$$ \dot{q}(t) = z(t) $$
$$ \ddot{q}(t) = \dot{z}(t) = A\dot{w}(t)-cz(t) - dq(t)$$

Let's imagine I have results at tn and I want results at tn+1. Then I computes K1, knwing $w(t_{n})$, $z(t_{n})$, $y(t_{n})$, $q(t_{n})$:
$$ k_{y,1} = w(t_{n}) $$
$$ k_{q,1} = z(t_{n}) $$
$$ k_{w,1} = -aw(t_{n}) - by(t_{n})+q(t_{n}) $$
$$ k_{z,1} = A\dot{w}(t_{n})-cz(t_{n}) - dq(t_{n}) $$

Here there's already a problem: I don't know $\dot{w}(t_{n})$.

Next step is to compute K2:
$$ k_{y,2} = w(t_{n}) + k_{w,1}*\frac{dt}{2}$$
$$ k_{q,2} = z(t_{n}) + k_{z,1}*\frac{dt}{2} $$
$$ k_{w,2} = -a\left(w(t_{n}) + k_{w,1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right) - b\left(y(t_{n}) + k_{y,1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right)+\left(q(t_{n}) + k_{q,1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right) $$
$$ k_{z,2} = A\left(\dot{w}(t_{n}) + k_{\dot{w},1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right)-c\left(z(t_{n}) + k_{z,1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right) - d\left(q(t_{n}) + k_{q,1}*\frac{dt}{2})\right) $$
Here again, I don't know $\dot{w}(t_{n})$ nor $k_{\dot{w},1}$ and I don't see any way to compute them.

Comment: Can you write them as first order systems? Then you can use $RK-4$.

Comment: You could solve the linear system for the first derivatives or replace $q=z+Ay$ to get an explicit system in $(y,z)$.

Comment: Are $q$ and $y$ functions of one variable ?

Comment: setting $r:=\dot{q}$ and $z=\dot{y}$ gives you a system $\dot{X}=MX$ where $X=\pmatrix{q&r&y&z}^T$ and matrix $M$ is $4 \times 4$.

Comment: @Moo I edited the question. As you can see I did but there's still a problem

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited the question. As you can see the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't understand, could you please detail?

Comment: Write the whole system as $\dot{x} = F(x,t)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$ then directly apply the RK4 formula from wikipedia/your book.

Comment: @whpowell96 I don't get it. What is x?

Comment: I just thought about something: I think i can remove $\ddot{y}$ from the second formula thanks to first formula.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with solving the linear system in the second derivatives. A well-known situation where you really have to solve is the double pendulum, where both second derivatives occur in both equations after the Euler-Lagrange formalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One just need to realize that:
$$\ddot{q}(t)=\dot{z}(t)=A\dot{w}(t)−cz(t)−dq(t)$$

can also be written as:

$$\ddot{q}(t)=\dot{z}(t)=A\left( −aw(t)−by(t)+q(t) \right)−cz(t)−dq(t)$$

thanks to first equation. And now the problem is simple and only rely on $w(t_{n})$, $z(t_{n})$, $y(t_{n})$, $q(t_{n})$